# Wcf RESTful service returning xml without xml schema

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Here is my code:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ThisPlan")]
public class ThisPlanTemplate
{
    [DataMember (Name = "length", Order = 1), XmlAttribute]
    public decimal length { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name = "height", Order = 2), XmlAttribute]
    public decimal height{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<MyClass> parts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get xml like the following:

```
<ThisPlan>
    <sections/>
    <length>100.00</length>
    <height>100.00</height>
</ThisPlan>
```

But I get this:

```
 <ThisPlan xmlns="some url">
    <sections xmlns:a="some url" i:nil="true"/>
    <length>100.00</length>
    <height>100.00</height>
</ThisPlan>
```

And how to remove the xmlns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this by specifying the XML namespace in your calls to Serialize().

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myObject));
var myNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
var myFile = File.Open(mypath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
myNamespace.Add("", "");
serializer.Serialize(myFile, myObject, myNamespace);
```

This code is for reference only and I would not use this in production, but it shows how you can specify your own namespace (or none at all). Hope this helps!